# How to implement dynamic styling of html on webview base on user preference

Tags: html, css, xml

Android Studio ... I would link to change html heading (h1 h2 h3 h4) colors in multiple html files based on Theme selected by user, I have all my html files linked to a css file, and I am looking for a way to change heading text color in css (thus in all html files) dynamically based on user preference.

```
//css
h2 {
  color: #008577;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: justify;
} 


//html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/stylesheet.css" />
</head>

//xml
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark1</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent1</item>
        <item name="backgroundcolor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="titletextcolor">@color/colorPrimary1</item>
        <item name="textcolor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
```

Is it possible to link css to xml? 
instead of color: #008577; ... color: "?attr/colorPrimary"

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simpler than I thought ..

placing the styles in the `SCC` file between the following solve the issue

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {}
```

Comment: The question is about "user preferenced theme" and the answer is about "responsive design"